# why radio button not passing clientID of asp control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

IDE: VS 2012

Designer code
Scenario 1:  with runat="server" (which is needed), javascript function doesn't work

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCost" runat="server"  ReadOnly="true" Text="250/-"></asp:TextBox>  


 <input type="radio"  name="myRadios" runat="server"  id="rb1" checked="true" onchange="javascript:UpdateClick(this,'<%=txtCost.ClientID %>');" value="1" /> Monthly
        <input type="radio"  name="myRadios" runat="server"  id="rb2" value="2" onchange="javascript:UpdateClick(this,'<%=txtCost.ClientID%>');" /> Weekly
```

Scenario 2:  runat="server" removed (which is needed), javascript function working.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCost" runat="server"  ReadOnly="true" Text="250/-"></asp:TextBox>  


 <input type="radio"  name="myRadios"   id="rb1" checked="true" onchange="javascript:UpdateClick(this,'<%=txtCost.ClientID %>');" value="1" /> Monthly
        <input type="radio"  name="myRadios"   id="rb2" value="2" onchange="javascript:UpdateClick(this,'<%=txtCost.ClientID%>');" /> Weekly
```

Javascript function:

```
function UpdateClick(myRadio, ClientID) {

        currentValue = myRadio.value;
        if (currentValue == '1') {
            var txtCostBox = document.getElementById(ClientID);
            txtCostBox.value = '250/-';
        }
        else {
            var txtCostBox = document.getElementById(ClientID);
            txtCostBox.value = '600/-';

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Problem:

So when I remove runat="server" in radio button, the code is working, and when I keep runat="server", Instead of getting actual client ID i am getting client ID    :

```
'<%=txtCost.ClientID%>'
```

I have a requirement where I need to keep radio button with runat="server", can you tell me how to fix above problem.

Comment: this makes no sense... runat=server means you need ClientID... so what you say seems reversed.

Comment: do you even need to pass `ClientID` of `txtCost`? Its ID appears static. Also it is unclear if your js is not running at all or if it just does not receive the `ClientID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the `onclick` on your code behind, in `Page_Load`.

```
rb1.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:UpdateClick(this,'" + txtCost.ClientID + "')";
rb2.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:UpdateClick(this,'" + txtCost.ClientID + "');"
```

Also, try changing the `"<%=txtCost.ClientID %>"` to: `"<%# txtCost.ClientID %>"`.

There are some other ways for doing this. You could also change your code:

```
function UpdateClick(myRadio) {

   var textObj = document.getElemmentById("<%# txtCost.ClientID %>");
   ...
}
```

Comment: rb1.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:UpdateClick(this,'" + txtCost.ClientID + "')";, nice solution, it worked., thanks

Answer (score 0):

runat server means runat server, javascript is client side. If you're using asp controls runat server would be required. As you're using a HTML input with the type radio runat server doesn't work.

Alternative:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="id" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item 2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your onchange call in radiobutton to as shown below

```
 <input type="radio"  name="myRadios" runat="server"  id="rb1" checked="true" onchange="javascript:UpdateClick(this);" value="1" /> Monthly
    <input type="radio"  name="myRadios" runat="server"  id="rb2" value="2" onchange="javascript:UpdateClick(this);" /> Weekly
```

and your javascript function to

```
function UpdateClick(myRadio) {
        currentValue = myRadio.value;
        if (currentValue == '1') {
            $('#<%=txtCost.ClientID%>').val('250/-');
        }
        else {
            $('#<%=txtCost.ClientID%>').val('600/-');

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: txtCost.ClientID needs to be passed as parameter, because they are on a user control. and the parent page can contain multiple instances of that user control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing this text box on an user control, or in a page that uses a Master page that is why you are not getting the ID with runat=server.

Change the client ID Mode of the text box to Static.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCost" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  ReadOnly="true" Text="250/-"></asp:TextBox>
```

Without Static the ID is something like textCost$1000blabla...

If you want a dynamic id vs. static, generate that javascript from the server side (using C# txtCost.GetClientID()) and you will have the full client id.